# How to determine the subshell 'level' in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

When entering subshells in bash with e.g. 
`su`, `bash`, `vim` (:sh command there), I occasionally find myself in a situation, where I don't know how deep I went (i.e how often I am allowed to exit to be at a specific position; reminds me a bit of the film Inception;) ).

Is there any tool that can show this subshell list/tree?

Comment: Uhm, `echo $SHLVL`?  or add `$SHLVL` to  your prompt?  Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-to-know-the-level-of-shells-i-am-in

Comment: `$SHLVL` only shows the actual level inside of bashes (but doesn't include e.g. `su`)  but the related article is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use command `pstree`. It shows process tree. Example:
[image: Process tree with different shells]

Comment: Yeah sure, I already know that (should have probably written it there), but the tree is mostly too huge to fit the console window, therefore a bit nasty to work with.

Comment: @dCSeven, try to execute `pstree -p -s $(echo $$)`

Comment: Oh, this is very helpful, thanks. I applied minor changes `pstree -pls $$`.

Comment: There still has to be a better way for doing this, but at least this one is better than mine before xD